# PekWM doesn't List Minimized Windows

Tags: window-manager, window-decorations

I recently installed the PekWM. I noticed when I minimize any window,it will be removed from `ATL+TAB` List. In other words "the minimized windows are not listed in `ALT+TAB` menu."
I want to know it is by design or it is a bug. If it is a bug is there any workaround to fix it.

Comment: It turned out it is by design but how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The icon menu shows a list of all currently "iconified" (minimized) windows. Hit <kbd>MOD4</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (i) to show it.

<kbd>MOD4</kbd> usually corresponds to the Windows keys. Run `xmodmap` to see which keys are bound to which modifiers. The left and right Windows keys are called `Super_L` and `Super_R` respectively.